# How to refer to a dynamically created div with JS

Tags: javascript, html

So I am creating div's onclick and giving them incrementally greater Id's. I want to then change the CSS properties of each div but I can't seem to select it with `document.getElementById`.

Obviously I'm missing something incredibly simple here, any advice or reading would be appreciated.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/genome314/coqkg5oz/1/)

Some relevant Javascript:

```
function createDiv(){
    i++;
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.id = "newDiv"+i;
    var e = document.getElementById("newDiv1");
    e.innerHTML = "hello";
    e.className = "newDivs";
    var x = 50*i;
    e.style.left = x+"px";
    e.style.top = 200+"px";
    //but nothing appears
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have not attached your `div` to the DOM tree, you should first attach it then try to grab its reference:

```
function createDiv(){
    i++;
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.id = "newDiv"+i;
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv); // <--- Append it here
    var e = document.getElementById("newDiv1");
    e.innerHTML = "hello";
    e.className = "newDivs";
    var x = 50*i;
    e.style.left = x+"px";
    e.style.top = 200+"px";
    //but nothing appears
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the div into the dom see fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/coqkg5oz/5/

```
function addDiv() {
    var objTo = document.getElementById('container')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = "new div"
   objTo.appendChild(divtest)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the element to the page, that's why it doesn't show up.

You don't need to use `getElementById` to get a reference to the element, as you already have a reference to the element.

Example:

```
function createDiv(){
    i++;
    var e = document.createElement("div");
    e.id = "newDiv"+i;
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    e.innerHTML = "hello";
    e.className = "newDivs";
    var x = 50*i;
    e.style.left = 100+"px";
    e.style.top = 200+"px";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/coqkg5oz/8/